# sitefinity 6 - events module error javascript

Tags: javascript, events, sitefinity

I've upgraded a website from 4.4 to 6.0 and found some issues. Some I already solved but I keep getting one error (javascript I suppose) on events module. When I try to preview/create new/publish/save draft I get the following js error:

```
TypeError: startDate is null

Unable to get property 'getFullYear' of undefined or null reference 
Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd, line 329 character 1


var range=this.get_rangeView().getRange();
var time=this.get_timeView().getRange();
var startDateTime=new Date(time.get_start());
var endDateTime=new Date(time.get_start());
var startDate=range.get_start();
var endDate=range.get_recursUntil();
startDateTime.setFullYear(startDate.getFullYear(),startDate.getMonth(),startDate.getDate());
```

I reckon that this is dynamically created by Telerik sitefinity and I'm not sure how to fix it. I went to the administration area and checked the relevant configurations and it seems to be everything ok (similar configs as sitefinity 4.4).

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this? I've tried to post a sitefinity forum thread on their website but they took way to much time to answer.

Cheers

Comment: What version of the Telerik.Web.UI do you have, and is the reference correct, am just wondering if somehow that hasn't upgraded?

Comment: Hi Sean. The version is correct and the reference too. I just confirmed and if the problem was that I'd have more problems with other modules.

Answer (score 2):

by any chance were you using external templates or a custom widget to show the events?

Sitefinity 6.0 apparently rebuilt the events module and it is no longer a simple, flat type. Instead it is a nested (hierarchical) type, with a parent calendar to which events are added (or multiple calendars if you need them).

So if you did any custom code or external template to display the content (in other words anything not out of the box that auto-upgraded itself when you updated to 6.0) you may need to rebuild this custom component to use the latest changes.

Consult the upgrade guide to 6.0 for latest breaking changes that one had the most differences, then compare your custom templates (if any) to the widget templates in the SDK: http://selarom.net/blog/2012/11/06/mapping-sitefinity-templates-from-the-sdk

I hope this is helpful!

Comment: I just started work on this project to do the upgrade... I'm not sure if we are using external templates or custom widgets but I dont think so. I got in touch with support and they suggest some changes. I've done them but nothing has changed. I'll investigate further. Thanks (again) Josh